# disable href link if javscript call return false

Tags: javascript, html

I have following code, but it doesnt work

---

```
<a href="Order-addCopy?id=15658">
  <img src="img/add.png" onclick="copyOrderPopupMsg()">
</a>


function copyOrderPopupMsg() {
    if (confirm("open the following link?")) {
        return true;
  } else {
        return false;
  }
}
```

---

How can I disable the href link if the user click "cancel" on the popup window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cancel navigation using that style of code you have to return *from the `onclick` function*.

You are returning from `copyOrderPopupMsg` but you don't do anything with the result.

You also have to handle the event on the **link** not the image inside the link.

Note, also that `confirm` returns a boolean, so wrapping it in an `if` that generates a boolean is pointless.

A link with no text content is also highly inaccessible, don't forget the `alt` attribute

```js
function copyOrderPopupMsg() {
  return confirm("open the following link?")
}
```

```html
<a href="Order-addCopy?id=15658" onclick="return copyOrderPopupMsg()">
  <img src="img/add.png" alt="Add">
</a>
```

Modern code also avoids `onclick` attributes as they have numerous issues (including lack of separation of concerns and weird scoping issues) so I recommend using `addEventListener` and making use of the event object.

```js
function copyOrderPopupMsg(event) {
  if (!confirm("open the following link?")) event.preventDefault();
}

document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', copyOrderPopupMsg);
```

```html
<a href="Order-addCopy?id=15658">
  <img src="img/add.png" alt="Add">
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I simple solution

```
<a href="Order-addCopy?id=15658">
  <img src="img/add.png" onclick="return copyOrderPopupMsg()">
</a>
```

Just add the return in onclick.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the link completely.

```
<img src="img/add.png" onclick="copyOrderPopupMsg()" data-href="Order-addCopy?id=15658">
```

```
function copyOrderPopupMsg(event) {
  if (confirm("open the following link?")) {
      window.location = event.target.dataset.href;
  }
}
```

Make sure you have a full URL. The current one is not valid for this operation.

If you want to use a relative path, you can create a hidden link and click it by function.

```
<a class="hidden click-when-confirmed" href="Order-addCopy?id=15658"></a>
```

```
function copyOrderPopupMsg(event) {
  if (confirm("open the following link?")) {
      document.quertSelector('.click-when-confirmed').click();
  }
}
```

Comment: This creates a major accessibility barrier. The link isn't accessible at all without JavaScript and since images are not designed to be interactive controls (and you haven't make it pretend to be one with `role` and `tabindex`) it will be skipped over for keyboard navigation and by screen readers.

Answer (score -1):

I think [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) would be the best in your case:

```js
function onclickA(e) {
  if (!confirm('open the following link?')) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="Order-addCopy?id=15658" onclick="onclickA(event)">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Yes_Check_Circle.svg" />
</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this: remove anchor tag and change to this

```
function copyOrderPopupMsg() {
    if (confirm("open the following link?")) {
        document.location.href="Order-addCopy?id=15658";
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This creates a major accessibility barrier. The link isn't accessible at all without JavaScript and since images are not designed to be interactive controls (and you haven't make it pretend to be one with `role` and `tabindex`) it will be skipped over for keyboard navigation and by screen readers.